# Tables not created after migration commands

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I use entity framework 6.4.0 code first in my project.

Here is context class:

```
class LibraryContext : DbContext
{
    public LibraryContext() : base("LibraryContext")
    {}
    public DbSet<Person> persons { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Book> books { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Review> reviews { get; set; }
}
```

Here is connection string from app file:

```
<add name="LibraryContext" connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-ND0H3GG\LOCALHOST;Initial Catalog=LibraryDB;User ID=sa;Password=blabla;"/>
```

Manually in the server called "DESKTOP-ND0H3GG\LOCALHOST", I created a DataBase, which is called LibraryDB.

when I run enable-migrations after it add-migration and update-database commands I expect to see three tables Persons, Books and Reviews.

But I don't see those three tables in the database. 
Instead of this, I see created the database called LibraryContext and three mentioned above tables 
in server (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB.

Here is how it looks:

[image]

Any idea why tables not created in LibraryDB?

Comment: Have you tried `public LibraryContext() : base("LibraryDB")`

Comment: @JohnWu thanks for post.Base have to contain name of the connection string.Why should I use LibraryDB instead.

Comment: [Link](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-in-code-first.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You should specify connStr when crete DbContext, i.e. in NET Core i am creating via my own DbContext extension:

```
public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection ConfigureSqlServerDbContext<TContext>(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection,  string connectionString) 
        where TContext: DbContext
    {
        serviceCollection.AddDbContext<TContext>(options => options.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.TrackAll)
                                                                   .UseSqlServer(connectionString)
                                                                   .UseLazyLoadingProxies());
        return serviceCollection;
    }
}
```

and i am running migration at application startup (in my example i am using appsettings.json for read config sections, FeesCalculationModelContext is my Db context):

```
        IList<IConfigurationSection> connections = _configuration.GetSection(ConnectionStringsSectionKey).GetChildren().ToList();
        string feesCalculationConnectionString = connections.First(item => string.Equals(item.Key.ToLower(), FeesCalculationConnectionStringKey.ToLower())).Value;
        FeesCalculationConnectionString = feesCalculationConnectionString;

        // 2. Configure context's
        services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer();
        // 2. b. Fees calc
        services.ConfigureSqlServerDbContext<FeesCalculationModelContext>(feesCalculationConnectionString);
        // migrate fees calculation ...
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        FeesCalculationModelContext feesCalculationDbService = serviceProvider.GetService<FeesCalculationModelContext>();
        feesCalculationDbService.Database.Migrate();
```

if you would like to specify db and update it with command you should have design time db context factory:

```
internal class FeesCalcMigrationsDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<FeesCalculationModelContext>
{
    public FeesCalculationModelContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        //todo: umv: move hardcoded conn string to migrationsSettings.json
        string startupPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"..\B2b.Data");
        string migrationsConfigFile = Path.Combine(startupPath, "migrations.Development.settings.json");
        IConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile(migrationsConfigFile, false, false);
        IConfigurationRoot configration = configurationBuilder.Build();
        string connectionString = configration.GetConnectionString("FeesCalculationConnectionString");
        DbContextOptionsBuilder<FeesCalculationModelContext> optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<FeesCalculationModelContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        return new FeesCalculationModelContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

For add migration and db update you should use following commands (NuGet Console, select project that contains you DbContext):

Add-Migration {name} -Context FeesCalculationModelContext -OutputDir FeesCalculation\Migrations

Update-Database -Context FeesCalculationModelContext